# C++ - expand stack at runtime

Tags: c++, memory, stack-overflow

How I can expand stack automatically when needed? (Until max I decide)

I am trying to create something that gets function pointer (Random one, I can't know what the function really needs) and create fiber with it.
But I need to create a lot of fibers but when they take more then the default I want it to expand automatically ,until max I decide.

REASON: I need to create a lot of fibers and if I create with them large stack then It'll take a lot memory too in the RAM. But if I'll create small stack it'll throw exception. (Stack Overflow)

But there should be large stack and small stack ,then I need to expand it automatically at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`CreateFiberEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create your fibers, you can use a small commit stack size, and a larger reserve stack size. Note, however, that whatever you specify for reserve is removed from the total memory available from the system. But, it is not committed to RAM unless you need it. Details are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you tell how slow it is? It takes a lot of time to expand? By what it multiplies the current stack?

Comment: @MessyCode: I can't tell you from personal experience. But from the explanation of how it works, the performance penalty is likely similar to allocating more memory from the heap. The page says it allocates 64KB at a time.

Comment: Oh ,I thought it'll reallocate the whole stack again ,and then copies the stack to the new stack ,and then delete the last stack. Thanks.